# Value of type 'Control' cannot be converted to 'CheckBox'

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am trying to loop through each row in a grid view, however when i am creating my loop i am getting error

aspx code for gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvContactList" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table blue">
     <Columns>
           <asp:CheckBoxField />
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

using code

```
   For Each row As GridViewRow In gvContactList.Rows
        Dim Row As GridViewRow = gvContactList.SelectedRow
        Dim chk As CheckBox = TryCast(Row.Cells(0).Controls(0), CheckBox)

        Dim SelectedEmail As String
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.Cells(4).Text) Or Row.Cells(4).Text.Trim() = "&nbsp;" Then
            SelectedEmail = Row.Cells(2).Text
        Else
            SelectedEmail = Row.Cells(4).Text
        End If

        txtEmailTo.Text = txtEmailTo.Text & SelectedEmail & "; "

    Next
```

the offending line is this but not sure how to fix it

```
Dim chk As CheckBox = TryCast(Row.Cells(0).Controls(0), CheckBox)
```

giving error

> Value of type 'Control' cannot be converted to 'CheckBox'

Comment: Use you debugger to find what type it actually is: likely to be some other control – hardcoding specific indexes into collections is fragile.

Comment: Is this a compile-time error or a run-time error?

Comment: i cant build it to get that far to debug it

Comment: i have added the gridview from the aspx page in the question

Comment: think i might have found the issue. `Dim Row As GridViewRow = gvContactList.SelectedRow` commented this line out and it got rid of my error

Comment: CType(gvr.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)

Comment: I voted to close your question because you just had malformed code - you found your issue and your question is no longer needed. You're right. you should of used for-loop variable `row` for the actions in your loop.

Comment: no worries... thank you for your help anyway